# No XDE for HoloLens Emulator

Tags: hyper-v, hololens-emulator

I can't find XDE.exe which is required to run the HoloLens emulator.

On http://peted.azurewebsites.net/start-hololens-emulator-without-visual-studio/, I've found out that you can run the HoloLens Emulator without Visual Studio.

It lists the following command.

`start “HoloLens” “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.14393.0\XDE.exe” /name “HoloLens Emulator 10.0.14393.0.peted” /displayName “HoloLens Emulator 10.0.14393.0″ /vhd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Emulation\HoloLens\10.0.14393.0\flash.vhd” /video “1268×720″ /memsize 2048 /language 409 /creatediffdisk “C:\Users\peted\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.14393.0\dd.1268×720.2048.vhd” /fastShutdown /sku HDE`

But, if I go to C:\Program Files (x86), there is no folder named "Microsoft XDE".

And even if I decide not to use XDE, the Hyper-V emulator gives this error.

I do not have enough reputation to post images, so here is what it says.

Virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdZve.png)

Please help.

Comment: Did you enable the Hyper-V windows feature? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: @maxwe Yes, I did.

Comment: To answer the first question why XDE isn't available - Are you sure you have the emulator installed from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator ? Also I did not have luck troubleshooting the emulator from my desktop but your error sounds similar to mine because my graphics card NVIDIA M2000M is not supported list. I use  a surface pro instead which has Intel 620. Good luck.

Comment: I have had the same issue a time ago. Try to deinstall the Hololens stuff and reinstall it, this helped me.